# Dificuldade com criação de consulta SQL

Tags: sql

Estou criando uma view com a seguinte consulta:

```
select 
    COD_PESSOA as ra,
    NOM_PESSOA as nome,
    COD_PESSOA_PAI as pai,
    COD_PESSOA_MAE as mae,
from PESSOA
```

Esta consulta retorna um resultado como este:

```
ra      nome          pai      mae
1       ciclano       4        5
2       fulano        6        7
3       beltrano      8        9
6       joão          NULL     NULL
9       maria         NULL     NULL
```

Eu quero que no lugar dos números retornados em `pai` e `mae`, retorne os nomes. Porém os códigos do pai e da mãe são `ra` também e estão armazenados na mesma tabela. Existe alguma forma de retornar os nomes no lugar nos `ra` com uma única consulta?

Comment: Qual é a chave primária?

Comment: Não tem chave primaria

Comment: Assim fica difícil, pois se o `cod_pessoa_pai` for 4 e quando você vai olhar no 4 encontra várias pessoas com este número, fica impossível saber-se qual delas é o pai. O mesmo acontece com a mãe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente isso:

```
SELECT
    a.cod_pessoa AS ra,
    a.nom_pessoa AS nome,
    p.nom_pessoa AS pai,
    m.nom_pessoa AS mae
FROM pessoa a
LEFT OUTER JOIN pessoa p ON p.cod_pessoa = a.cod_pessoa_pai
LEFT OUTER JOIN pessoa m ON m.cod_pessoa = a.cod_pessoa_mae
```

Neste caso, eu estou juntando a pesssoa `a` com o seu pai (que é a pessoa `p`) e também juntando com a mãe (que é a pessoa `m`). Uso o `LEFT OUTER JOIN` para que ele não exclua pessoas que não tenham pai ou mãe registrados (nestes casos, o pai e/ou a mãe serão `NULL`).

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigada!

Answer (score 1):

É possível também utilizar sub selects na consulta:

```
select 
    PES.COD_PESSOA as ra,
    PES.NOM_PESSOA as nome,
    (select PAI.NOM_PESSOA from PESSOA as PAI where PAI.COD_PESSOA = PES.COD_PESSOA_PAI) as nome_pai,
    (select MAE.NOM_PESSOA from PESSOA as MAE where MAE.COD_PESSOA = PES.COD_PESSOA_MAE) as nome_mae
from PESSOA as PES
```

Comment: Deu erro: `Subquery returned more than 1 value`

Comment: Tenta usar o [Select FIRST](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_first.asp) no sub-select, mas a consulta não deveria retornar mais de um registro, pois estamos filtrando pela chave primária (COD_PESSOA) que não deveria se repetir.

Comment: COD_PESSOA não é chave primária. Esse valor se repete, é uma tabela de matrículas e tem matrículas de vários anos, por isso o valor se repete (Acho uma maneira meio burra de modelar mas não posso mudar isso)

Comment: O SQL Server não está reconhecendo o first: `'FIRST' is not a recognized built-in function name`

Comment: No link que coloquei no comentário tem a sintaxe para cada DB. Apenas salientando, você deve ter uma chave primária. Da uma lida [nesse artigo](http://www.devmedia.com.br/clausulas-inner-join-left-join-e-right-join-associacao-de-tabelas-sql-server-2008-parte-2/18930)